# Transforming GdkPoint

Tags: gtk, cairo

How can I transform a gdkpoint? Say:

```
GdkPoint p2 = sometransform.transform(P1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be done with PangoMatrix, here the x and y coordinate needs to be set to x and y value and apply the current transform on the (x,y) values.

```
    PangoMatrix elementMatrix = PANGO_MATRIX_INIT; 

    GdkPoint elementCenter;

    // do some other operations here like translation, rotation etc... 

    double *x, *y;
    *x = elementCenter.x;
    *y = elementCenter.y;

     pango_matrix_transform_point(&elementMatrix,x,y);
```